Winter Bash 2018 Preparations
Winter Bash 2018 is coming up fast, so I thought it would be a good idea to start a discussion on how we'd like to handle things this year.
It seemed like it went well last year, and it was fun to be able to offer a prize. TLG is able to support this event with up to €500 EUR in prizes shipped to multiple addresses. Prizes need to be in stock on German S@H, and prices are in German MSRP.
If you have thoughts on what would make good prizes, how prizes should be awarded, or just general thoughts on Winter Bash 2018, this is the place to do so.

I think it would be great to have another competition on similar terms to last year, perhaps this time we could award prizes to more people considering the amount LEGO are willing to sponsor.

I’m all for it as well. Let’s get more prizes, different categories, giving multiple people a chance of winning. We could do most hats, prizes for a special hat, even a LEGO hat-building competition (though one of us already scored high marks in the Stack Exchange hat competition last year).

Unfortunately, nobody apart from a few members of Stack Exchange staff know which hats will be released so it will be a bit difficult to give prizes for particular hats until the event starts. I like the idea of having a competition similar to last year as well as a creative contest (hat building).

One thing to keep in mind, it might be tough to predict which sets will still be available after the holiday spending period concludes, around the same time Winter Bash ends. Some sets may end up back ordered or sold out.
